# Xamarin Android project runtime error Firebase library

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-notificationhub

We are trying to integrate to Azure notification hub in xamarin forms project. Added the below nuget packages and implemented the classes but while running the application , getting the below error. We are not using any code shrinker but still getting this error. Any help would be appreciated.

- Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base
- Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging
- Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.Android

''Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: com.google.firebase.components.MissingDependencyException: Unsatisfied dependency for component Component<[class com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging]>{1, type=0, deps=[Dependency{anInterface=class com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=interface com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsApi, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=interface com.google.firebase.platforminfo.UserAgentPublisher, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=interface com.google.android.datatransport.TransportFactory, type=optional, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=interface com.google.firebase.heartbeatinfo.HeartBeatInfo, type=required, direct=true}]}: interface com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsApi''

Comment: According to your error message, it seems that you may miss some configuration for azure hub, please take a look [Configure the Android application for notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-notification-hub#configure-the-android-application-for-notifications) firstly.

Answer (score 0):

This error was because I missed adding these permissions in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

Now the issue is that the OnNewToken method in FirebaseMessagingservice is not getting invoked. Tried reinstalling as well. Any thoughts on this?